# Get the SHA-512 of any SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sha, sha512

A common practice to compare two text file is to use the SHA-512 [or any other realted SHA algo]. If two SHA results are not the same then the files are not exactely the same.

I would like to do the same with two SQL queries. I just want to know if the queries gives 100% identical result or not with a SHA-512 [or sha-256 would be OK as well]?

Is that possible to perform that? I am using SQL Server...

Comment: Do you want to compare SQL query text or query result? Anyway different queries may return same results in specific conditions (you will get a lot of false positive)

Comment: To a first approximation, you can slap `FOR XML AUTO` on the bottom of your query and `HASHBYTES` the result. SQL Server 2014 and earlier can't hash more than 8000 bytes, though, so if you're using those versions that's a problem.

Comment: Why not use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) between your two queries and see if anything survives? Then you don't have to worry about ordering or any other funky things that might get picked up in a hash or checksum and cause your check to fail.

Comment: I think doing it that way is complicate your life unnecesarily. As @JNevill says, why don't you use the `EXCEPT` clause?

Comment: `I just want to know if the queries gives 100% identical result` **[Counterexample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=324eeaa808f2ecdcb0c8690586fe6433)**

Comment: @JaimeDrq Simply because I did not know this EXCEPT clause... As I used different keywords in my Google research I didn't find the EXCEPT  clause. Well I will check for that ...

Comment: No problem @S12000. Basically, the except clause compares 2 subsets of data, and returns those records in A not present in B. Take care with it, because you have also to compare B with A to be sure that both sets are equals

Comment: @lad2025 Yes but your example use different data. In my very specific case I assume that the data will not change...

Comment: @S12000 Still it doesn't  prove that queries are the same. Simple scenario JOIN and LEFT JOIN and all records from both tables matches. **[Counterexample 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60f41a53b75fc5a02420f2ce13d37777)**

Comment: @JaimeDrq OK I will have a look. [The reason why I was thinking about the SHA-512 method is because I do it a lot of time when I work with text files... But if EXCEPT is easier then of course I can use it ]...

Comment: @lad2025 I understand but this in my case this is not a problem at all. In my case I am interested in the result I get with specific data  that not change... I do not care if my queries product different result later on with different data...

Comment: Careful with the `EXCEPT` order and implicit conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to help...

It's understood that both queries return the same columns in the same order.

You must do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  ([YOUR_QUERY_A]
   EXCEPT
   [YOUR_QUERY_B]) -- A_B
  UNION ALL
  ([YOUR_QUERY_B]
   EXCEPT
   [YOUR_QUERY_A]) -- B_A
  ) EX
```

If returns 0, both queries return the same

For test purposes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  (select 1 a
   EXCEPT
   select 1)
  UNION ALL
  (select 1
   EXCEPT
   select 1)
  ) EX
```

Change some inner query and look what changes

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example SQL that uses 2 methods.

1. [FOR
   XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server)
   &
   [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql)
2. [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTest;
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    col1 decimal(10,2), 
    col2 varchar(30)
);

insert into #tmpTest (col1, col2) values 
(1,'val1'),
(null,'val2'),
(3,null),
(4,'val4')
-- ,(5,'monkeywrench')
;

declare @SQL1 VARCHAR(1000);
declare @SQL2 VARCHAR(1000);
declare @SQLHASH VARCHAR(3000);
declare @SQLEXCEPT VARCHAR(5000);

set @SQL1 = 'select col1, col2 
from #tmpTest
where (col1 is null or col1 between 1 and 4)
';

set @SQL2 = 'select col1, col2 
from #tmpTest
where (col2 is null or col2 is not null)
';

set @SQLHASH = 'select 
IIF(LEN(query1.x) = LEN(query2.x) AND HASHBYTES(''SHA2_512'', query1.x) = HASHBYTES(''SHA2_512'', query2.x),''true'',''false'') as SameHash
from (
    '+ @SQL1 +'
    order by 1, 2
    for xml auto
) query1(x)
cross join (
    '+ @SQL2 +'
    order by 1, 2
    for xml auto
) query2(x)';

--select @SQLHASH as SQLHASH;
execute(@SQLHASH);

set @SQLEXCEPT = 'select 
IIF(count(*) = 0,''true'',''false'') as SameRecords
from (
    select * from
    (
        '+ @SQL1 +'
        except
        '+ @SQL2 +'
    ) as q1exceptq2

    union all

    select * from (
        '+ @SQL2 +'
        except
        '+ @SQL1 +'
    ) as q2exceptq1
) q';

--select @SQLEXCEPT as SQLEXCEPT;
execute(@SQLEXCEPT);
```

In this example, both dynamic queries return 'true'.

But do note that just because the result sets are the same, doesn't mean that the criteria used are equivalent.
It might just be bad luck that they are currently returning the same results.
*(just uncomment the monkeywrench record to get false from both)*

Also, about the FOR XML. When one of the ORDER BY is different, then the resulting XML and HASH will also be different.

While with an EXCEPT you can only add an ORDER BY at the end, because it sorts the combined resultset.