# Oracle 11g: table checksum or hash

Tags: sql, hash, plsql, oracle11g, checksum

I would like do a checksum against different views implementing different approach supposed to produce the same result (assuming each view contains no duplicates and have the exact same columns).

**Questions**

1. What is the easiest way to compute a table checksum or hash ?
2. Is a checksum the only way to compare in Oracle if 2 tables are identical ?

Note: 
Googling around I found some old answers such as [this one](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:41727263557318).

Comment: [Get the SHA-512 of any SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724104/get-the-sha-512-of-any-sql-query) - if you want to comapre if 2 queries are equivalent to each other then please read comment section

Comment: Thanks. Which comment section ? If on the link I provided, it is from 2005

Comment: I meant comments from link that I provided. Especially examples what could go wrong even if two queries return same resultset

Comment: OK. I have read but sounds heavy (e.g. DBMS_COMPARISON - http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm). Was wondering if there was others approach such as computing the checksum of each rows, sorting these checksum row and doing a checksum of all them. If so, what is the function in Oracle doing a checksum ?

Comment: I recommend blog https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/techniques-for-comparing-tables/ and search for techniques described there.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea on how to do an `Group by (HASH)`. I would be interested knowing how this hash is calculated. The blog doesn't provide any example but performance comparison between Technics.

Comment: The optimiser has two possible approaches to computing results of `group by` queries. I don't think think this is relevant to your question, though.

Comment: If you are looking for a hash function, you can use [`ora_hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ORA_HASH.html).

Comment: Thanks! Will try this ora_hash function. Up voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a checksum the only way to compare in Oracle if 2 tables are identical ?

No, since you have no duplicates, you can use the `MINUS` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Will return all the rows from `Table1` that do not exist in `Table2`. If zero rows are returned then all the rows in `Table1` also exist in `Table2`.

If you want to check the tables in both directions then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.*, 'T1' AS "WHERE" FROM Table1 t1
  MINUS
  SELECT t2.*, 'T1' FROM Table2 t2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT t2.*, 'T2' FROM Table2 t2
  MINUS
  SELECT t1.*, 'T2' FROM Table1 t1
)
```

Again, if no rows are returned then the tables are identical.

If you are comparing tables with duplicates and want the same number of duplicate rows in each table then you can use something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, /*...*/ ColN,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, /*...*/ ColN ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         AS rn
FROM   table1
MINUS
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, /*...*/ ColN,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, /*...*/ ColN ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         AS rn
FROM   table2
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested both and sounds to work.
Just changed both direction with: SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT VIEW_B2.*, 'T1' AS t FROM VIEW_B2
  MINUS
  SELECT VIEW_B3.*, 'T1' FROM VIEW_B3
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT VIEW_B3.*, 'T2' as t FROM VIEW_B3
  MINUS
  SELECT VIEW_B2.*, 'T2' FROM VIEW_B2
);

Comment: Does adding distinct in the select clauses allows these solutions to work in case of duplicates ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange Using `DISTINCT` (or even without using `DISTINCT`) would let you check whether there are rows in the first table that are not in the second table but not that you have the same number of duplicates in each table. I've updated with a method of checking that you have the same number of duplicate rows in each table.

Comment: Thanks! Sound no needs checksum. Tested. Marked as correct and up voted!